# Is there a Bookmark Contentprovider for Chrome to get browser history

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-contentprovider, bookmarks, android-contentresolver

I have an app that use ContentResolver to get the Browser history data with Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI. It works well with the stock Android browser. Now Google is moving to Chrome as the default browser. Does Chrome provide similar Contentprovider? I searched all over the web but could not find any information on this. Is there a doc for Chrome on Android released by Google yet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks") instead of Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI... it worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/ThAoOAYOPCk indicates that this should now be possible.

If Chrome is the system default browser (which it should be in Nexus7) the BOOKMARKS_URI authority should automagically resolove Chrome's bookmarks.  If it is not the default https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138755 indicates that the content-provider URI is `content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks`