# Get Redirected URL From Browser - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, redirect, browser

Here's my problem I want to authorize my app from a user.
for this the api provides me OAuth 2.0 process

I have a link " A " which contains my app key and my redirection link

eg. http://www.apiprovider?api-key=MY_API_KEY&redirect=`REDIRECT_LINK`

link A when opened in a browser asks for the users username and password and authorizes my app, after successful authorization the user is redirected to `REDIRECT_LINK`

the `REDIRECT_LINK` is encoded with a key which I need to store in a variable

eg. https://www.twitter.com/some_profile?`key=Asc545AS454dS44as`

I dont want the user to visit the redirect link, i just want to **fetch the url** and then **close the browser**, **the page should not open**.

I have used this code to open the link in a browser

```
Intent httpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            httpIntent.setData(Uri.parse("LINK_A"));
            startActivity(httpIntent);
```

Comment: don't open it in the browser, use a WebView. Or, make an HttpGet and retrieve the Location-Redirect header.

Comment: I cannot use HttpGet since the redirection occurs after the user enters valid username and password and for that the page (link A) has to be shown to the user. It cannot happen in the backend.

Comment: ok! but how do I track the redirection, I mean closing the webview just after getting the redirected link

Comment: i think there is are a few methods in webview and webclient to intercept requests, allowing you to not load a page.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your page in WebView, you app can listen for any URL change with [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) callback.

If you prefer to open the stock browser, you can start a service that will periodically poll the latest URL:

```
String lastDate = "0";
…
String newDate = Long.toString(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
    Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION,
    Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " IS NOT NULL AND " + Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " > ?",
    lastDate,
    Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String url = cursor.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX);
}
cursor.close();

lastDate = newDate; // update the timestamp
```

When you find that the `url` matches your expected change, you can switch to your Activity and continue within the context of your app.

It is possible to close the browser, but it may not be polite, from the POV of your end-user. Imagine for example that she has 5 open tabs with important information, and all this is destroyed!

Note that this method *[can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240622/192373)* for Chrome browser, with slightly different content provider: **content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks**